# How to toggle attr(contenteditable value) for elements that has same classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I created a button that creates elements that has same classes and at the same time they have their own button for toggling contenteditable attribute, but for some reason, the button on the first element toggles that content editable attributes of all elements. How should i fix this?

```js
$(".addroomtest").click(function(){

            $(".roomslist ul").append("<li ><div id='ed' class='editroombutton'>edit</div><div class='editablecont' contenteditable='false' '> Room 301</div></li>"); 
  
 

});



$( ".editroombutton" ).click(function() {
 
    var value = $('.editablecont').attr('contenteditable');

$('.editablecont').attr('contenteditable') === 'true' ? 
$('.editablecont').attr('contenteditable', 'false') : 
$('.editablecont').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have no closing tag for the editable content. Try adding a `</div>` before the ending `</li>` when you append the elements and see if the closure fixes it.

Comment: hello thankyou for correcting that but it still didnt fixed the problem. i think the edit button fail to bind to its parent element that has the editable content when created but i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Hmm, well, you do also have an extra single quote in the attributes section of the last div.
Also, I'm not sure how your ternary if (?:) is working right now; ternary expressions are expressions and not statements, meaning they aren't supposed to run anything, but instead be a value, such as:
`var a = b ? c : d;`